# Meaning and purpose of なくはある

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the sentence:

> この班の編成自体
> よく分から**なくはある**んだし

What is the purpose of saying it like that instead of just「よく分からないし」?

Comment: Does the sentence continue?

Comment: Here's more of the conversation: https://imgur.com/a/TizDu3T
The context is that members of a group are showing concern because an enemy has temporarily joined their group (by the command of a higher-up)

Comment: Related or duplicate [「高くはある」と「高い」の違い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19698)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ku-form + はある` is a way to apply a contrastive-wa to an i-adjective. For example, 面白くはある is translated as "it's true that it's interesting (but...)", "it *is* interesting" or "it's interesting, at least", depending on the context.

- [What are the proper usages and the meaning of くはある / くはない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93629/5010)
- [「高くはある」と「高い」の違い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19698/5010)
- (BTW you can add は to a verb too: [は after te form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98206/5010))

In your case, the "adjective" happens to be (分から)ない, the negating auxiliary that conjugates like an i-adjective. And when nothing is *explicitly* contrasted using けど/が, we can use "at least" to convey the nuance.

> この班の編成自体よく分からなくはあるんだし。
>
> Well, we can at least say the organization of this group itself is not quite understandable.